# Kendo Grid with custom filter menu not working

Tags: javascript, web-applications, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've been really struggling to get a custom filter menu to work with the Kendo Grid.

I've stripped down everything to a bare minimum and I still can't get it to work. I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matbeard/VvJ2N/2/) which is a direct copy of Kendo's own demo -- it doesn't work here either.

The `cityFilter` function is not called when activating the filter on the City column.

The demo works on the Kendo site though, so I'm stumped.

Comment: @Pabloker is right. It's because some (likely) bugs. You have to download the new version 2012.3.1315 (just released today).

Comment: filterable.ui option is added in the service pack release (2012.3.1315) and does not exists in previous versions of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you are using the correct references..

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pabloker/VvJ2N/6/